# Get pointer level from type rather than from variable

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I try to make it possible to display pointer depth as integer number of asterisks - for example `int***` would be `3`. But instead of calculating it from type, I wrote code that requires that every level of pointer have to be properly initialized. Here is what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

// no pointers involved
template <class T>
std::size_t get_pointer_level(T)
{
    return 0;
}

// final value reached, returning depth
template <class T>
std::size_t get_pointer_level(std::pair<std::size_t, T> arg)
{
    return arg.first;
}

// function that accummulates depth
template <class T>
auto get_pointer_level(std::pair<std::size_t, T*> arg)
{
    return get_pointer_level(std::make_pair(arg.first+1, *arg.second));
}

// initial function called for pointer argument
template <class T>
auto get_pointer_level(T* arg)
{
    return get_pointer_level(std::make_pair(std::size_t(1), *arg));
}


int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;
    auto b = &a; //int*
    auto c = &b; //int**
    auto d = &c; //int***
    auto e = &d; //int****
    std::cout << get_pointer_level(e) << std::endl; //4
}
```

I'm pretty sure that it's very possible to make it work just with type alone. I imagine syntax would be something like that:

```
get_pointer_level<int****>::value
```

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the solution! Here is final functionality that I wanted to accomplish:

```
template <std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
struct is_smaller
{
    enum {value = (A < B)? 1 : 0};
};
template<std::size_t Target, typename T, std::size_t Actual = get_pointer_level<T>::value>
T value_at_level(T pointer)
{
    static_assert(Actual==Target, "Invalid target level!");
    return pointer;
}

template<std::size_t Target, typename T, std::size_t Actual = get_pointer_level<T*>::value,
         typename = std::enable_if<is_smaller<Target, Actual>::value>::type>
auto value_at_level(T* pointer)
{
    return value_at_level<Target>(*pointer);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    auto b = &a; //int*
    auto c = &b; //int**
    auto d = &c; //int***
    auto e = &d; //int****

    std::cout << "int from int****: " << value_at_level<0>(e) << std::endl; //ok
    std::cout << "int* from int***: " << value_at_level<1>(d) << std::endl; //ok
    std::cout << "int** from int**: " << value_at_level<2>(c) << std::endl; //ok
    std::cout << "int*** from int*: " << value_at_level<3>(b) << std::endl; //error
    std::cout << "int**** from int: " << value_at_level<5>(a) << std::endl; //error
}
```

Comment: Curious: what's the proposed use-case for this?

Comment: Obligatory: [You do not ant to be a three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouMightBeaThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: This seems like a trivial bit of TMP; why so complicated?

Comment: What I want to achieve is to be able to dereference pointer at given level. The desired integer value is needed for checking how many dereferencing is needed. Example: I want to get `int*` value from `int*****` value. Integers would be `1` and `5`, so amount of dereferencing required would be `4` times.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An exercise in partial specialization:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, std::size_t S>
struct get_pointer_level_impl
{
    static const std::size_t value = S;
};

template<typename T, std::size_t S>
struct get_pointer_level_impl<T*, S> : get_pointer_level_impl<T, S+1>
{

};

template<typename T>
struct get_pointer_level : get_pointer_level_impl<T, 0>
{

};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << get_pointer_level<int>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << get_pointer_level<int*>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << get_pointer_level<int**>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << get_pointer_level<int***>::value << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're OK with calling it as `get_pointer_level<int*>()` instead of `get_pointer_level<int*>::value`, then a recursive `constexpr` function works just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
constexpr int get_pointer_level()
{
    return !std::is_pointer<T>::value ? 0 : 1 + get_pointer_level<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << get_pointer_level<int>() << '\n';
    std::cout << get_pointer_level<int*>() << '\n';
    std::cout << get_pointer_level<int**>() << '\n';
    std::cout << get_pointer_level<int***>() << '\n';
    std::cout << get_pointer_level<int****>() << '\n';
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58efb52b37c6bcf0)

Answer (score 4):

Use a helper class to determine the pointer level.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T> struct PointerLevel
{
   static const std::size_t value = 0;
};

template <class T> struct PointerLevel<T*>
{
   static const std::size_t value = PointerLevel<T>::value + 1;
};

// no pointers involved
template <class T>
std::size_t get_pointer_level(T)
{
   return PointerLevel<T>::value;
}

int main(void)
{
   int a = 10;
   auto b = &a; //int*
   auto c = &b; //int**
   auto d = &c; //int***
   auto e = &d; //int****
   std::cout << get_pointer_level(a) << std::endl;
   std::cout << get_pointer_level(b) << std::endl;
   std::cout << get_pointer_level(c) << std::endl;
   std::cout << get_pointer_level(d) << std::endl;
   std::cout << get_pointer_level(e) << std::endl; //4
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about use typeid(your type).name() ??

```
std::string s( typeid(int***).name()); 
size_t n = std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), "*");
```

Comment: Mangled names can't use `'*'` character can they?

Comment: Disregarding being non-portable, it's not a compile time solution, also even assuming non-mangled name, it would only work for simple types (what does this return for `std::vector<T*>*`?)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I found "However, you should never rely on the exact content, like for example returned by std::type_info::name(), as this is implementation specific with respect to the compile."